# Angular sub-component passed model, but delay on UI

Tags: angular, model, binding

I have an angular application.

I have a div that uses *ngIf to appear when a button is clicked.
When it appears, the containing component gets some models passed into it

```
<div *ngIf="hideInitialSetupControls">
      <app-referral-report style="position: relative; left: 25px;" [selectedClinic]=theSelectedClinic [consult_reason_textarea]=myTextarea [patientData]=patientData [referringProviderData]=referringProviderData></app-referral-report>
   
</div>
```

,and then in that referral-report template I Have bindings.

EG:

```
  <span style="font-weight: bold;">Consult to:</span> {{selectedClinic.ClinicName}}<br/>
                    {{selectedClinic.Address}}<br/>
                    {{selectedClinic.PostalCode}}<br/>
            <strong>Phone:</strong> {{selectedClinic.Phone}}<br/>
            <strong>Fax:</strong> {{selectedClinic.Fax}}<br/>
            <strong>Email:</strong> {{selectedClinic.Email}}<br/>
```

However, when the UI is displayed I only see the place holders, until I click into some content and then the bindings bind.

I tried using a change detector with no resolve.
Does anyone know why my bindings are not shown right away?

Thanks,
Christopher

**UPDATE:**
I have pie (or is it egg) on my face. There was an unhandled exception preventing my ngInit from completing the first time around. I will leave this here.

I just added a try{....}catch(error){alert(error)} to my code and the issue was obvious.

Comment: Because `selectedClinic` is undefined until you select a clinic

Comment: ngIf adds/removes DOM elements. What is the change detection for the the component? OnPush etc.

Comment: selectedClinic gets populated via the same call which moves to the report component 

    onClinicSelection(clinic: ClinicModel)
    {
      this.theSelectedClinic = clinic;
    }

Regarding Change detection, I trigger it via ngIf so that trigger the change... that said, I also tried with 'private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef' and called detectChanges

I am just adding extra error handling to see if some unhandled exceptions are causing the issue....

Comment: Thanks Guys, you let me to the issue.... I feel foolish now, an unhandled exception was occuring preventing the ngInit to complete... then I am guessing later when I click it retriggers ngInit.